# finding and replacing values in list in python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this exercise that I need to solve for class. What I have to do is changing all values lower than 50 to 50 and print the updated dictionary.

**this is the dictionary**

```
precios = {

    'ACCIONA': [78.60, 84.95, 77.20],

    'ACERINOX': [5.88, 51.25, 58.42],

    'INDITEX': [49.99, 57.89, 68.5],

    'ENEGAS': [0.5, 0.78, 48.75],

    'FERROVIAL': [78.58, 24.25, 65.45]

}
```

**this is what I have done so far:**

```
for i in precios.values():
    for item in i:
        if item < 50:
            item = 50
```

However, when I try to print the dictionary with the changes, it just prints the original dictionary.

Comment: Here's a hint: `max(50,x)`, and `map(function, list)` and `dict.items()` can be helpful. I don't want to give you the answer because it's an assignment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a for loop rather than a for-each loop as your inner loop:

```
for l in precios.values():
    for i in range(len(l)):
        if l[i] < 50:
            l[i] = 50

print(precios)
{'ACCIONA': [78.6, 84.95, 77.2], 'ACERINOX': [50, 51.25, 58.42], 'INDITEX': [50, 57.89, 68.5], 'ENEGAS': [50, 50, 50], 'FERROVIAL': [78.58, 50, 65.45]}
```

Comment: thank you! was looking for an answer like this! very clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
for k,v in precios.items():
    #k = key, v = value
    #list comprehension to make new list of dictionaries values
    new = [50 if nums < 50 else nums for nums in v ]
    #update
    precios[k] = new
```

output

```
{'ACCIONA': [78.6, 84.95, 77.2], 'ACERINOX': [50, 51.25, 58.42], 'INDITEX': [50, 57.89, 68.5], 'ENEGAS': [50, 50, 50], 'FERROVIAL': [78.58, 50, 65.45]}
```